# getline() getting incorrect characters

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with `getline()`. The first line in my text file is `C C0 H:7 E:7 P:10`, but printing `line` (which holds the string returned by `getline()`) yields `C▒Hdtors`. What is happening here?

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    string line,tmp_holder;
    int tmp_h, tmp_e, tmp_p, counter=0;
    vector<string> info;
    ifstream finp(argv[0]);

    map<int, Circuit> circuits;
    vector<Juggler> jugglers;

    if (!finp.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Unable to open input file " << argv[0] << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (getline(finp,line)) {

        tmp_holder = "";
        info.clear();

        if (line[0] == 'C') {

            cout << "Line: " << line << endl;
```

Comment: I am guessing that your are passing the name of the file from command line. It is stored in argv[1] , not 0.

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

argv[0] is your program name, not the file name. Change

```
ifstream finp(argv[0])
```

to

```
ifstream finp(argv[1])
```